# Magento Customer Login and Account Creation content is not displaying

Tags: customer

I have been working on a magento projects for some months now. So I have added my custom online payment integration.

After adding payment integration the content on all the page disappears leaving only the header and the footer. I have now recover the page that I can access back-end through cms->page but the login and registering a new customer account page cannot be done from the back-end.

The url for the login page is

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your layout.xml file check 1column.phtml file and template for persistent/customer/form/login.html

Thank you